# Define concrete function return type without `as` keyword

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have two base types `UserResponse`, `LogoutUserResponse` and one common type for these two types `ApiResult`.

```
export type UserResponse = { user: number };
export type LogoutUserResponse = { logout: boolean };
export type ApiResult = UserResponse | LogoutUserResponse;
```

How can I specify return type for results fn2 and fn3.

```
const fn = (): ApiResult => ({ user: 2 }); 
const fn2 = (): UserResponse => fn() as UserResponse;
const fn3 = (): LogoutUserResponse => fn() as LogoutUserResponse;
```

If I clear `as UserResponse` the compiler will say:

> Type 'ApiResult' is not assignable to type 'UserResponse'.
>     Property 'user' is missing in type 'LogoutUserResponse' but required in type 'UserResponse'.

I suppose generics should help me, but I don't know how.

Comment: the `ApiResult` type is equal to the intersection of `{ user: number }` and `{ logout: boolean }`, which is the empty object type: `{}`. You can use `&` in place of `|`, or (maybe better) you could make `fn2` and `fn3` return `ApiResult` and, when you access the result, you can use a type guard

Comment: fn() returns a UserResponse. It does not return a LogoutUserResponse. So, first, why are you using ApiResult as its return type and not the more accurate UserResponse type? And second, why are you using `fn() as LogoutUserResponse;` in fn3 since you know that this is incorrect: the response is not a LogoutUserResponse? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @JBNizet This is just simplify of usage. Realization of fn is more complex - it will  return promise (request to server which will define what data response contains).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you don't know in advance if it returns a UserResponse or a LogoutUserResponse. So you should check what it returns first, and the use `as UserResponse` or `as LogoutUserResponse`. Is that what your question is about?

Comment: @CristianTraìna, Yes, maybe this is an option. Change fn2,fn3 types to `ApiResult` and verify type through type guard inside function.
But want to make sure I didnt missed another resolve with generics usage. Eventually i want to get something like this
`const fn2 = (): UserResponse => fn<UserResponse>()`

Comment: @JBNizet, almost. The real point that interest me is solution with generics usage maybe or not. So thats same answer to CristianTraìna.

Comment: But that doesn't make it clearer to me: when you call fn(): can you know in advance what it will return or not? If you can, then calling `fn<UserResponse>()`makese sense. If you can't, then it doesn't.

Comment: @JBNizet, I will pass argument url to fn(url: string). So, yes, I will know what will return.

Comment: So fn() should be defined as `fn<T>(url: string): T`. And you can call it using `fn<UserResponse>('some url')`, which will return a UserResponse. Or, using type inference: `const r: UserResponse = fn('some url')`.

Comment: Yeah, thats it, but I don't really know how whole example will be written.I have an error when define function type of T.

Comment: [My try](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqBnYUBKwOQB2WcAvHAN5wCuWUAXHIdQLYBG2cAvgNwCwAKFCRYCZKgAyEAOYRqMTNjwEIxVOSoAbGXJiM2ECJuABDQt34DBw6PCQo4AQTABLZdU3xyi3PiJZBODgAHzgpWXkfZX9gS0FBAGNVDHgAM0J6AB4AFQA+AAoASlJcuGyyOCKyUvyqWmxGACZuQp44ROS0wmbyIsYov2T1UvTMgZU1AtaO4i6AZgq+sJ1Iumih6rh0qpMMZYiFNcG1SyTiI2AAOm1pfO3C1qA).
Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `const fn: <T>() => T = <T>() => ({ user: 2 } as unknown as T);`

Comment: This also looks weird. But thanks, JBNizet! Something has already cleared up, I'll think about it later.